# If I put accented syllables(these syllables have higher pitch and higher volume) on each beat of music does it count as syncopation?

Tags: theory, rhythm, lyrics, syncopation

If I put accented syllables(these syllables have higher pitch and higher volume) on each beat of music does it count as syncopation since I’m also accentuating beats 2 and 4?All of this is in 4/4 time. Also, if I do this can it create dissonance?

Answer (score 1):

Syncopation is **shifting** the accent from a strong part of a measure to a weak part, so to achieve it you not only need to place accent on the weak part, but you also make sure it does not appear on the strong part.

Let's consider the word *syncopation*. The stressed syllables are SYN and PA.

The following examples show the word aligned naturally (without syncopation) with the metric accents in a 4/4 bar:

[image]

The syllables SYN and PA occur at the strong beats 1 and 3.

What would happen if we shifted this rhythm by one quarter note?

[image]

The stressed syllables fall on the weak beats. The performer may attempt to accent the stressed syllables SYN and PA, but the music won't support this. On the other hand the unstressed syllables *co* and *tion* will be naturally accented. More likely the performer will actually accent the unstressed syllables *co* and *tion* instead of the stressed SYN and PA – actually you can hear it quite often in popular music.

The following two example show the actual syncopation:

[image]

In the first example the syllable PA is **moved** from the strong 3rd beat to the weak 2nd. As no note appear on the 3rd beat, the syllable remains accented – actually syncopation typically creates an accent that is stronger than natural metric acent. In the second example the syllable SYN is syncopated in a similar way.

In popular music I find syncopation more often using eight-notes than quarter notes. The following example shows both syllables SYN and PA syncopated as they appear an eight-note before the metric accents.

[image]

> Also, if I do this can it create dissonance?

The word *dissonance* in music is used only to describe relations between pitches or harmony, not the rhythm. Of course all elements of music interact, so e.g. if you syncopate a note by singing it earlier, while the band is still playing the previous chord, it *may* result in a dissonance. Such dissonance doesn't necessarily sound bad, e.g. it may foreshadow the chord change.

Comment: _"...if you syncopate a note by singing it earlier,... it may result in a dissonance."_ -- that may be called an _anticipation_, and sometimes an accompanist anticipates entire chords. You _could_ look at these anticipations as creating dissonances in some cases, but that would seem to emphasize vertical harmonic structure in a way that doesn't always feel appropriate.

Comment: @exnihilo yes, I agree

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of syncopation is shifting emphasis from where it's normally heard. In order, the first beat of a bar will generally be the most emphasised, followed by beat 3 (in 4/4). Then would come beat 2, and lastsly beat 4. Emphasising any of thos ebeats, or making them the first note of a phrase is, well, ordinary, commonplace.

The shifting emphasis or beginning of a phrase to *anywhere* else will constitute syncopation. So, the quaver points in between the 4 main beats, or even semiquavers in between them, will make far more effective syncopations. Moving an anticipated 1st beat note to the last beat of the bar before is also an effective syncopation - even though the note may fall on beat 4 - a slightly important one, as mentioned - it *anticipates* the most important beat, which remains not silent, but decaying.

As far as dissonance is concerned, yes, it can be produced in syncopation, although in my last scenario, often the harmony will be syncopated too, to align with the 'pushed' note. Sometimes syncopation can produce dissonance which again causes the listener to be affected - a sort of double whammy.

Comment: So your saying the melody can land on beats 2 and 4, and still not be syncopation? Do you have any references